# i am getting error unexpected end of input in my node js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
 const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/restDB",{useNewUrlParser:true});

const articleSchema={
 title:String,
content:String
 }
 const Article = mongoose.model("Article",articleSchema);

app.get("/articles",function(req,res){
  Article.find(function(err,foundArticles){
  if(!err){
   res.send(foundArticles)
  }else{
   res.send(err)
   }

  });
 });

   app.post("/articles",function(req,res){
     const newArticle = Article({
    title:  req.body.title,
     content:  req.body.content
    });
   newArticle.save(function(err){
    if(!err){
    res.send("succes")
     }else{
    res.send(err)
    }
       })
   app.delete("/articles",function(req,res){
       Article.deleteMany(function(err){
      if(!err){
       res.send("success")
    }else{
     res.send(err)
    }
   });
    });



    app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log("Server started on port 3000");
     });
```

i am making request through postman the same code was running fine but it started giving this error
before this error code was doing fine and i dont understand whats happening

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
      at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1071:16)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:27)

        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

please help me with that it doest include html file i am making requst with postman and using mongodb as a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please recheck your closing bracket

your api with endpoint articles isn't closed.

```
 app.post("/articles", function (req, res) {
    const newArticle = Article({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    });
    newArticle.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send("succes")
        } else {
            res.send(err)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then I think you need mark the answer. :-)  that's great. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error` typically means either you are missing a closing parenthesis, brace, bracket, or similar character somewhere in your code or you are trying to `JSON.parse()` a string that is missing such characters.

Run your code/JSON string through a javascript linter (e.g. jshint) to find syntax errors.